# Set time for ElasrAlert slack notification

Tags: elastalert

I have ElastAlert set up and all of my alerts coming in once per day with aggregate set at days:1. But I get the alert in the evening and I'd prefer to get the slack alert in the morning, the alerts from the previous 24 hours included.
Can I set the time of day I want my notification to come through?